# My program is running, but it is minimized

Tags: python, minimized

```
def Poland():
    import turtle as t
    t.bgcolor("black")
    t.width(10)
    t.color("white")
    t.forward(50)
    t.right(90)
    t.penup()
    t.forward(10)
    t.right(90)
    t.pendown()
    t.color("red")
    t.forward(50)

Z = eval(input("Your country: "))
if (Z == Poland):
    Poland()
```

When I run this program and answer the question "Your country" with Poland, it does work (It opens "Python Turtle Graphics" window and draws a flag), but it is minimized. PLS help. I am new at this.

Comment: Unrelated, but why `eval(input(..))`? (Are you aware you can wipe your hard disk that way?)

Comment: It is in the task bar (minimized) Example: When you open google and click that "-" in the high right corner It will bring you to your desktop and left it open in the task bar.

Comment: what can I use instead of that?

Comment: what can I put instead of eval(input(…))

Comment: A better tutorial, a more modern version of Python, or, if all else fails, reading [the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#input).

Comment: Can you pls make example with my code so I can use it in other programs instead of eval(inpu(…))

Comment: Sure. Go to [this link](https://www.python.org/downloads/) to install a version that is not hopelessly out of date, obsolete, and no longer supported.

Comment: In Python3, `Z = input("Your country: "); if (Z == 'Poland'): ...`. For Python2, replace `input()` with `raw_input()`

Comment: thanks, the latest version installed, what should I do next

Comment: `eval(input())` takes user input and then executes it as a Python program, which might be unsafe to run. What you probably want instead is just to take an input string and compare it against some other value.

Comment: sorry, I do not really understand, can you pls show an example with eval(input(…)) and without it?

Comment: sry, I did not see your second msg

Comment: 10q so much, everything is working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to maximize the turtle window just use:

```py
t.Screen().cv._rootwindow.wm_state("zoomed")
```

or

```py
t.Screen().cv._rootwindow.state("zoomed")
```

This works because turtle is nothing other than tkinter window.

But the window will be played in the background.

To pop it up in the first layer:

```py
t.Screen().cv._rootwindow.attributes("-topmost", True)
```

More tkinter in turtle
`t.Screen().cv._rootwindow.here_comes_the_tkinter_window_command`